# Safely handling DoExpressCheckoutPayment response using InstantPaymentOnly

Tags: php, paypal

I'm looking into implementing Paypal's ExpressCheckout API into my web application because I need a payment system that immediately tells me if the transaction was successful in order for the application to reserve items of extremely limited quantities.

I think I have a basic understanding of how the system works (I've messed around with it in sandbox), but I wanted to make sure that my understanding of how DoExpressCheckoutPayment works is correct.

(Begin my understanding)

If I specify InstantPaymentOnly for PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD in SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckout, I only need to check the response's ACK code to contain 'success'/'successwithwarning' and PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS to contain 'Completed' to make sure that the money was guaranteed to have transfered.  Additionally, if the ACK code is of failure or PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS is anything but 'Completed', my application can safely release the items because the payment for the transaction will never come.

(End my understanding)

Is my understanding correct, or will these assumptions lead to me not receiving payment for items that I've reserved or releasing items that I'll eventually receive payment for?

Thanks in advance.